# can not initialize static final variable in try/catch

Tags: java, static, initialization, final, static-initializer

I am trying to initialize a static final variable. However, this variable is initialized in a method which can throw exception, therefor, I need to have inside a try catch block.

Even if I know that variable will be either initialized on try or on catch block, java compiler produces an error

> The final field a may already have been assigned

This is my code:

```
public class TestClass {

  private static final String a;

  static {
    try {
      a = fn(); // ERROR
    } catch (Exception e) {
      a = null;
    }
  }

  private static String fn() throws Exception {
    throw new Exception("Forced exception to illustrate");
  }

}
```

I tried another approach, declaring it as null directly, but it shows a similar error (In this case, it seems totally logic for me)

> The final field TestClass.a cannot be assigned

```
public class TestClass {

  private static final String a = null;

  static {
    try {
      a = fn(); // ERROR
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
  }

  private static String fn() throws Exception {
    throw new Exception("Forced exception to illustrate");
  }

}
```

Is there an elegant solution for this?

Comment: Try with passing by a temporary variable `b` in your `try...catch`, test the result and following it, assign `a` value

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can assign the value to a local variable first, and then assign it to the `final` variable after the `try`-`catch` block:

```
private static final String a;

static {

    String value = null;
    try {
        value = fn();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    a = value;

}
```

This ensures a single assignment to the `final` variable.

Answer (score 1):

**Final variables can only be set once.**

You cannot (and do not need to) set `a` to `null` in the `catch` block.

Make the following change:

```
public class TestClass {


      private static final String a = setupField();

      private static String setupField() {
        String s = "";
        try {
            s = fn();
        } catch (Exception e) {
          // Log the exception, etc.
        }
        return s;
      }

      private static String fn() throws Exception {
        return "Desired value here";
      }
```

Comment: This will produce a different error - `The blank final field a may not have been initialized` - since now `a` is not guaranteed to be initialized by the static initializer block.

Comment: Well, now you have two assignments to a final variable (first error) and a method that should return a String but has no return statement (second error).

Answer (score 0):

private static final String a = null;

properties that are final are only initialise once. Either in the Constructor or the way you did it here. You cannot give 'a' a new value after you have given it the value null. If you dont have a final you can set the value via the fn function

Answer (score 0):

It's because `final` variable can only be assigned only once and it can't be reassigned again.

Nothing to do with `try/catch`

Comment: "`final` variable can only be assigned only once at the time of declaration". That's not true, haven't you heard of blank finals?

Comment: there is a link with `try...catch` in the way that code in the `try` is effectively "tried", so that `a` was assigned already when reaching the `catch` if there is an error, contrary to what the OP expected.